# How to add Panel in android?

Tags: android, panel

I want to add a panel in android activity.I'll try explain its behaviour.

It should show small arrow on right side of my activity, If i click on that a panel having few buttons should slide out consuming around 20%-30% of current activity.

Somewhat same like menu appears on screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Sliding Panel](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/06/slidingpanelayout-android-making.html) and [Sliding Drawer](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/08/android-sliding-drawer-example.html) are two option to look for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) widget. However, this widget will only slide up and down on older SDK versions.

Else, you should consider using fragments (using the compatibility API if necessary). You can look for some explanations about how the GMail app is built, or the HoneyComb gallery example to get information about animating fragments.

Comment: Yes thats what i was looking for.

Comment: Any chance you could fix the second link? This is the main reason why we now disallow link-only answers, they quickly go stale and provide no value to future visitors.

Comment: Yep, site is down. Removed the link and added some extra info instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example of Panel

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/panel_title"
            android:id="@+id/groupTitle"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blue" />

Here you add panel content...

</LinearLayout>
```

You also need to add in drawable resource broder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke
       android:width="3dip"
       android:color="#d3d3d3" />
</shape>
```

And color in values/Colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <item name="blue" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
</resources>
```

And panel Title in values/Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
  <string name="panel_title">Panel 1</string>
</resources>
```

As for button and animation that can be added separatly.